# Shopware 6 Hot Module Reloading in Production mode does not reload compiled files

Tags: livereload, webpack-hmr, shopware6

I am using the production version of Shopware 6.4.7 with my own custom theme installed and activated. When I start the watcher via `bin/watch-storefront.sh` the live reload server seems to start normally and compiles my files. When I go to the live reload URL with the supplied port (http://shopware1.local:8889) I can see my website and previous SCSS changes are compiled.

What does not happen is the following:

- JS changes are not compiled
- I do not see any logging I would expect when running HMR
- SCSS changes are not reloaded, even though my terminal output states they are recompiled
- JS changes are not reloaded, even though my terminal output states they are recompiled

When I run a full build using `bin/build-storefront.sh` all assets are compiled as expected. What could be the issue here?

Comment: I believe it should work - do you get any error messages?

Comment: Hi @Alex I get no error output whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who also ran into this: After re-installing my setup I figured it out; you should set up the site in dev mode in order for livereload to work. Contrary to what the SW6 training video's specify.

Comment: Are the instructions for setting up the site in dev mode so long and complicated that were unable to be put here?

Comment: No they are not: Simply choose dev mode in de the setup wizard.

Comment: Yea, so I have set it up in dev mode. Maybe you mean some other dev mode? This is why it's good to put detailed info